How to check if date of a particular row in an array is less than today's date
I have a portfolio tracker on Google sheets, which summarises the final amount of shares of a stock (adjusting for shares bought and sold). I use below Google App script to read through the array from this portfolio tracker spreadsheet based on certain conditions.

function myPortfolio(tickers, values, types, dates) {
 var total = []
 var sums = {}

 for(i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++){

 var t = tickers[i].toString()
 var ty = types[i].toString()
 var dt = dates[i]

 if(t != "Cash" && ty != "Dividend"){
     if(t in sums){
      sums[t] += Number(values[i])
     }
     else {
        sums[t] = Number(values[i])
     }
   }
  }

 for(var tickers in sums){

 if(sums[tickers]>0){
   total.push([tickers, sums[tickers]])
  }
 }
return total
}


I need to have an additional condition to the "if statement": dt <= today(). How do I do that. Can someone help please.
I don't have coding background, so couldn't try anything

I would try this edit
function myPortfolio(tickers, values, types, dates) {
 var total = [];
 var sums = {};
 var todaysDate  = new Date();    //pulls todays date

 for(i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++){

 var t = tickers[i].toString();
 var ty = types[i].toString();
 var dt = new Date(dates[i]);   //makes this a date

 if(t != "Cash" && ty != "Dividend" ** dt < todaysDate){
     if(t in sums){
      sums[t] += Number(values[i]);
     }
     else {
        sums[t] = Number(values[i]);
     }
   }
  }

 for(var tickers in sums){

 if(sums[tickers]>0){
   total.push([tickers, sums[tickers]]);
  }
 }
return total
}


In Apps Script you can use dates the same way you can in Javascript so we can make use of the Date constructor.
Entering Date() with no parameters will create a date with today's date. Using the constructor with parameters will allow you to create dates based on strings and other formats, and in this case I'm assuming from your array another date, here's how your code would look:
function myPortfolio(tickers, values, types, dates) {
 var today = new Date(); 
 var total = []
 var sums = {}

 for(i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++){

 var t = tickers[i].toString()
 var ty = types[i].toString()
 var dt = new Date(dates[i]);     //make sure your array uses valid formatting for these date values

 if(t != "Cash" && ty != "Dividend" && dt <= today){
     if(t in sums){
      sums[t] += Number(values[i])
     }
     else {
        sums[t] = Number(values[i])
     }
   }
  }

 for(var tickers in sums){

 if(sums[tickers]>0){
   total.push([tickers, sums[tickers]])
  }
 }
return total
}

